# How to select a minimum subgraph of a graph containing any k nodes

Tags: graph, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, subgraph

I am trying to solve the problem below. It is like k-minimum-spanning-tree and the steiner tree problem, but it is with a graph.

- We have a non-negative undirected weighted graph G = (V, E).
- For every pair of vertices v1 and v2 there exists an edge e12. In other words, every vertex is connected to every other vertex.
- We shall create a subset of the vertices U that contains k vertices.
- Our goal is to select the n vertices in U such that the sum of the edges from each vertex in U to every other vertex is minimized. In other words, we want to select the vertices in U so that the sum of all the edges from the nodes in U outwards is minimized.
- 1 < n < number of vertices

Am I correct that neither k-MST or the Steiner tree approximation solutions will work? If so, what is this problem called? And what are the solutions? I am fine with using heuristics or approximations to solve this problem and don't need formal proofs.

Comment: I don't have much recent experience in these kinds of problems so I have to ask a couple of possibly dumb questions: Are k and n the same thing? Are U and V the same thing? Is your third point just a dumbed down version of your fourth point?

Comment: Not exactly. V represents the set of all vertices in some graph. E represents the set of edges in this graph. k is just an integer that represents how many vertices we want (it is an input to the problem, along with the graph G containing V and E). U represents a subset of k vertices that we want to select with some algorithm (U is the output to the problem). So point 4 is saying that the k vertices our algorithm chooses to be in U should be chosen such that the sum of the length of their edges to all vertices (including those not in U) is minimized.

Comment: So if you think of a matrix where each column/row is a vertex and each cell a weight. So U is a subset of rows, and then you want to minimize the sum of the weights in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that K-MST or Steiner tree won't work - they produce a tree only, while you need a graph with special properties, e.g. with 0 cost between vertices within U and minimal cost for all other edges if I understood your problem.

While [juancn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873453/5823050) answer looks correct, I think that using something like [metaheuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic), e.g. [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), or [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) approaches will be better.

For metaheuristics:

1. Compute edge-cost for each vertex
2. Greedely pick *k* vertices - it forms your *initial solution*
3. In case of SA, start modifying initial solution be including/excluding new vertices one by one (maybe there is a better approach, you should study it yourself)
4. Given enough time, it should converge to good enough solution

For constraint satisfaction:

1. Objective: select *k* vertices from a given graph. For each vertex introduce 
   a Boolean variable, if it's **1** - the vertex is a part of U, otherwise, it's **0**. Then your objective is:

> sum (vertices==1) = k

2. Subject to: the minimal sum of edges weights between *k*-vertices and others. If I'm correct, the cost for edges in U is 0. I don't know how to formulate such constraints properly, but they should be rather simple.
3. Run a solver with timeout, let's say a few hours.

For the last approach, constraint satisfaction, memory could be a problem - you need a lot of memory to represent a fully-connected graph and all constraints. Still, check [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/), [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/) and [coin-or](https://www.coin-or.org/) projects.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a faster algorithm, but the trivial one (if I got your explanation right) is:

- Build an array/map where you hold the sum of the weights for each edge from vi to any other vertex. If you think at the matrix representation of the graph, where each row/column is a vertex and each cell is a weight on an edge. The array would be the sum of each row.
- Generate all k-sized sub-sets of vertices, keep the one whose sum is the smallest.

If there are n vertices this is explores `n!/(k! (n-k)!)` such combinations.